# How to add more inputs to a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

What would be the correct approach to add additional inputs that aren't images, e.g. time, to the CNN. I initially thought of adding more inputs to one of the densely connected layers at the end of the CNN architecture, but I am note sure how this would affect the backprop.

Does anyone know how to implement this using Keras or something similar?

Comment: If you only have time, you may use Conv1D. If you have a stream of images (such as a video), you can try Conv3D. Can you give more details on "additional inputs": additional to which original features?

Comment: "Time" as in the time of the day the image was taken.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to add non-image/non-spatial/non-temporal features can be at the feature vector level i.e. just after CNN's flatten layer, just before the FC layers.
Use Merge layer in Concat mode

Let's say you have an image and also some text attached to it.
You can use a 2D CNN for the image as usual. For the text you can use another CNN or an RNN. Then flatten it's feature vector and use Merge layer as mention above